# Why does the ubuntu-server package depend on update-notifier-common?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, software-uninstall

I'd like to uninstall `update-notifier-common` and implement my own update checking solution, but every time I try, I'm warned that doing so will also uninstall the ubuntu-server package:

```
apt purge update-notifier-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-server* update-notifier-common*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1460 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

What function does `update-notifier-common` provide for `ubuntu-server`, and why does `ubuntu-server` depend on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [file list of `update-manager-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/update-notifier-common/filelist) shows some files that would of use on a server:

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier
/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
/etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol
/etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot
/etc/update-motd.d/98-reboot-required
```

It adds various useful messages to MOTD, and sets the reboot required notification for kernel packages. Could these be put in another package? Perhaps. Should they be? I don't see a compelling reason.